# glDrawArrays: attempt to access out of range vertices in attribute

Tags: javascript, webgl, cocos2d-js

I'am trying to draw 2 triangles with `gl.drawArrays + gl.TRIANGLES` but it just won't work (BTW I am using cocos2d-js).

Here is what I have done.

First code for add vertex.

```
addVertex:function(x, y) {
    this._vertexCount += 1;
    this._vertexArray.push(cc.p(x, y));
    this.updateVertexArray();
}

updateVertexArray:function() {
    this._vertices = new Array(this._vertexCount * 2);
    this._uvs = new Array(this._vertexCount * 2);

    var width = this.getContentSize().width;
    var height = this.getContentSize().height;

    for (var i = 0; i < this._vertexCount; i ++) {
        var vertex = this._vertexArray[i];
        this._vertices[i * 2 + 0] = width * vertex.x;
        this._vertices[i * 2 + 1] = height * vertex.y;

        this._uvs[i * 2 + 0] = vertex.x;
        this._uvs[i * 2 + 1] = 1 - vertex.y;
    }

    this._vertexView = new Float32Array(this._vertices);
    this._uvView = new Float32Array(this._uvs);

    gl.bindBuffer(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, this._vertexBuffer);
    gl.bufferData(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, this._vertexView, gl.DYNAMIC_DRAW);

    gl.bindBuffer(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, this._uvBuffer);
    gl.bufferData(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, this._uvView, gl.DYNAMIC_DRAW);
}
```

And the draw part:

```
draw:function () {
    gl.bindBuffer(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, this._vertexBuffer);
    gl.enableVertexAttribArray(cc.VERTEX_ATTRIB_POSITION);
    gl.vertexAttribPointer(cc.VERTEX_ATTRIB_POSITION, 2, gl.FLOAT, false, 0, 0);

    gl.bindBuffer(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, this._uvBuffer);
    gl.enableVertexAttribArray(cc.VERTEX_ATTRIB_TEX_COORDS);
    gl.vertexAttribPointer(cc.VERTEX_ATTRIB_TEX_COORDS, 2, gl.FLOAT, false, 0, 0);

    gl.drawArrays(gl.TRIANGLES, 0, this._vertexCount);
}
```

Then it works fine with one triangle :

```
customGLNode.addVertex(cc.p(0.0, 0.0));
customGLNode.addVertex(cc.p(0.5, 0.0));
customGLNode.addVertex(cc.p(0.5, 0.5));
```

The result is :

[image]

And it also works fine with another triangle:

```
customGLNode.addVertex(cc.p(0.6, 0.6));
customGLNode.addVertex(cc.p(1.0, 0.6));
customGLNode.addVertex(cc.p(1.0, 1.0));
```

The result is:

[image]

But when I try to draw the two triangles together:

```
customGLNode.addVertex(cc.p(0.0, 0.0));
customGLNode.addVertex(cc.p(0.5, 0.0));
customGLNode.addVertex(cc.p(0.5, 0.5));
customGLNode.addVertex(cc.p(0.6, 0.6));
customGLNode.addVertex(cc.p(1.0, 0.6));
customGLNode.addVertex(cc.p(1.0, 1.0));
```

Nothing shows and I have the error saying:

`GL ERROR :GL_INVALID_OPERATION : glDrawArrays: attempt to access out of range vertices in attribute 1`

But it seem like the vertices array is all fine :

[image]
[image]

I use 2 floats per attribute (position/uv) per vertex,

now I have 2 triangles

=> 6 vertexes

=> 12 floats for position array

=> 12 floats for uv array

Any advice will be appreciated, thanks :)

Comment: What do you mean by "I use 2 bit"? 2 bits means you could only store 4 different values... I guess you meant that you use 2 floats per attribute?

Comment: You're right, sorry for my choose of words. I have edited the question.

Comment: Where are you calling `gl.createBuffer();` from?